# Changing my AIM alias in Empathy doesn't work

Tags: empathy

I try to change my nickname for my AIM account in Empathy. And the change doesn't seem to take. Whatever I do, it just kind of stays the same. It works fine for my Google talk account... Iunno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a bug](http://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24707) in Telepathy.

Comment: Well, gee. That sucks. Any positive prognosis?

Comment: The best thing you can do is subscribe to the bug to be notified of progress. Or perhaps help find someone who might be able to help fix the bug.